# golang: how is "func() interface {}" and "func() *MyStruct" incompatible types?

Tags: go

Suppose I have code, where a function accepts another one as an argument:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func personBuilder() * Person {
    return &Person{Name: "John"}
}

func printRetrievedItem(callback func() interface {}){
    fmt.Print(callback());
}

func doStuff(){
    printRetrievedItem(personBuilder);
}
```

This results in error `cannot use personBuilder (type func() *Person) as type func() interface {} in function argument`. If I change `personBuilder` return type to `interface{}`, it works, but in real project I'm working on I want to have a concrete type for clear design and TDD purposes.

Does Go support such method signature generalization? What are the workarounds, if you could not change the `personBuilder` part (e.g. you have a lot parameterless functions that return different type of struct, and you want to build a consumer function that accepts any of those builders as argument)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pkg `reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) for this. (Note however that the solution of [**@OneOfOne**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145587/oneofone) is more idiomatic).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func personBuilder() *Person {
    return &Person{Name: "John"}
}

func printRetrievedItem(callback interface{}) {
    vals := reflect.ValueOf(callback).Call([]reflect.Value{})
    fmt.Println(vals[0].Interface())
}

func main() {
    printRetrievedItem(personBuilder) // &{John}
    printRetrievedItem(func() string { return "hello" }) // hello
}
```

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/PH9ieDOwdF)'s an example in the playground.

Comment: Hm, yeah, solves my question, but obviously not really an elegant code to be used in prod code. Maybe I'll just rethink the application structure in general (use channel to exchange objects between producer and consumer? don't know)

Comment: @uiron agreed. Just wanted to show it was technically possible :-)

Comment: @jabclab just keep in mind that function calls through reflection are extremely slow.

Answer (score 4):

One workaround is to define an inline function that calls `personBuilder`.

```
printRetrievedItem(func() interface{} {return personBuilder()});
```

<kbd>[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ct5pR1CLVh)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Either do a wrapper like @GrzegorzŻur suggested or define your own interface and make your `xxxxBuilder` return it:

```
type Namer interface {
    Name() string
}

type Person struct {
    name string
}

func (p *Person) Name() string {
    return p.name
}

func personBuilder() Namer {
    return &Person{name: "John"}
}

func printRetrievedItem(callback func() Namer) {
    fmt.Printf("%T: %v", callback(), callback().Name())
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but in my case I don't know common interface for an object (the consumer function just passes received object to third party reflection based functions, like JSON serialization).

Answer (score 4):

You can create an interface with a method that returns an `interface{}`:

```
type Thinger interface {
    Thing() interface{}
}

func (p *Person) Thing() interface{} {
    return p
}

func printRetrievedItem(t Thinger){
    fmt.Print(t.Thing());
}

func doStuff(){
    printRetrievedItem(personBuilder);
}
```

This is just an example, please use a better name!

To answer your question, `fun() A` is not a `func() interface{}`, for the same reason that `[]A` is not an `[]interface{}`. It's explained very well in the [go wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice).

Comment: yeah, though about that part, but in my particular case I wanted to decouple item producer and item consumer. I did not want to enforce special interface for item producer to implement so the consumer can use it. Thanks for explanation on compatibility though.